# Remove carriage returns not being removed during export, PHP

Tags: php, csv, carriage-return

I'm working on a job app at work. It works great for everything except when the job applicant pushes the return button in the text fields. I have a field asking for their work history. So they enter company name [then pressed enter] address [then pressed enter] what they did for work [then pressed enter].

When the csv is exported it does this:

1|John|Smith|company name

address

what they did

2|Amy|Doe|company name

How can I make it do this:
1|John|Smith|company name|address|what they did|2|Amy|Doe|company name

This is the CSV generator:

```
// Fetch Record from Database
$output = "";
$table = "job_seeker"; // Enter Your Table Name 

$sql = mysql_query("select seek_id, f_name, m_intial, l_name, add1, add2, city, state, zip,    country, cell_num, home_num, email, app_position, app_workhist from $table WHERE $SER");
$columns_total = mysql_num_fields($sql);

// Get The Field Name

for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
$heading = mysql_field_name($sql, $i);
$output .= ''.$heading.'|';
}
$output .="\r\n";

// Get Records from the table

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
$output .=''.$row["$i"].'|';
}
$output .="\r\n";
}

// Download the file
$date_st = "" . date("Y-m-d") . "";
$filename = "".$date_st."_exportall.csv";
header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);

echo $output;
```

As you can see I'm trying to get rid of the carriage return by mysqli_real_escape_string:

```
$app_workhist = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['history']);
```

I've tried some "cleanup script". That didn't work either. Am I Doing some thing wrong. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I could propose a way to remove the newlines, but won't your CSV be broken with this approach?  If the user types 3 lines for one record and 4 for the next, the number of columns in each line would differ. It'd be impossible to parse!

Comment: sure. I thought of trim() and trim \r\t\n "". before the data is inserted but it will only trim before and after the string. which is fine if someone was return happy at the end of the input.  What were you suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by using a str_replace()
    str_replace(array("\r\n","\r"),"",$string);